# const reference and returned value

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, return-value

Having code

```
int test(){
   return 5;
}
```

and

```
int main(){
   const int & t = test();
   cout << &t << endl;
}
```

By stantards , we can assign temporary object to const &  variables and extend their lifetime to lifetime of const & variable.

Does that mean that const & variable has the same place in memory ( memory address ) as returned value ( temporary object)?

E.g

If i want to return value from func, it gets copied into register and afterwards assigned to variable , which would mean memory place wouldnt be the same, or it was created on stack , and simply const & variable is alias for that place in memory?

Also why is `const` required , it is just the way c++ implemented it?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: You can also use `int&&` to extend lifetime if you don't want the `const`.

Comment: @Jarod42 good to know , but the question was more of trying to figure out how exactly it works bts. Is it the same memory address?

Comment: Note that just because `&t` returns a memory location doesn't mean that you can use that for anything. It's very likely that the compiler does not even bother to write the temporary into that memory location, but leaves it in a register.

Comment: reference should be just alias that means they have the same address as the variable they refer to. Doesn't it mean that `t` is just alias to temporary object thus  `&t` holds address of that temporary object?

Comment: @ZanLynx Isn't the compiler required to store the variable in memory once the address is output? [Compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/2AZDmo) seems to confirm that.

Comment: @zett42: No, it is only required to act "as if" it was. If you just take the address but never use it for anything, it never has to write it to memory.

Answer (score 0):

`int` is usually returned as a register, so the compiler will create a new temporary to store the result.

The returned object may not have had storage, so strictly not necessarily the same address

Answer (score 0):

When you return by value, result is situated in temporary allocated stack variable, or may be in case of simple types such as `int` in register (i suppose it's compiler specific).

Reference internally is no more than just a pointer which is prohibited to be `null` by language syntax.

So: returned value is temporary allocated on stack, and `const &` to it is pointer also on stack that points to temporary variable.

Comment: A reference is an alternative name for a thing. It doesn't have to become a pointer if there's no need for one in the compiled code. Assuming that a reference exists as a pointer can be a mistake.